# How to configure schema name for mapped entity / table in JPA / hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an application which need to access 2 schemas at runtime, and the schema names need to be configured when deploy, because the name are different for each deployment (for assembly testing, integration testing, performance testing...)

I know JPA / hibernate can specify schema on @Table annotation, but I need to make the schema configurable, is there anyway to add a post processor / event listener so I can modify the hibernate meta info, and change the table schema with my configuration?

Currently I'm looking into rewrite my own HibernateJpaVendorAdapter / HibernatePersistence, but definitely this is not a good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Does one instance of your application access only one schema, or does one running instance access two different schemas at the same time (for example `liveA` and `liveB`)?

Comment: One instance need to access two schemas in one transaction. I don't want to use JTA cause it's too expensive, else I can use 2 entity managers and map each of them to different default schema.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to investigate the `persistence-unit-defaults` element in your `META-INF/orm.xml` file.  This allows you to specify a default schema and catalog for a persistence unit.  That may or may not meet your needs, depending on how you figure out what schema to access in your code.  Also be aware that Hibernate has been riddled with bugs in this area for years and years.  Nevertheless, it might be better than writing custom code.

Comment: If I can use JTA and define 2 entity manager, this should work. But my environment doesn't allow for that. Thanks.